# Find text between two same strings

Tags: javascript

Would there have any library that could get text that's between two words or symbols from a string? Here's what I want to do:

```js
var string = "rainbow Text rainbow"
// I want to find "Text" because it's between the two words "rainbow"
string.getTextBetween("rainbow", function(text) {
    console.log(text) // should log "Text"
})
```

If there aren't any library, how could I make that?
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Like I'm not very good with RegEx, I tried some things that wasn't working

Comment: Is the search case sensitive? Like would the search find `"Text"` in the string `"RAINbow Text raINbow"`? Also - it helps to at least show what you've tried

Comment: Yes it is, but Maheer Ali gave a perfect answer already

Comment: Want to save you A** So, go to learn Algorithms then you would solve hard problem  than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly more flexible version:

```js
const betweenTokens = (t1, t2 = t1) => 
  (s, i = s.indexOf(t1), j = s.indexOf(t2, i + 1)) => 
    j > -1 ? s.substring(i + t1.length, j) : ''

console.log(betweenTokens('rainbow')("rainbow Text rainbow"))
console.log(betweenTokens('<!--', '-->')("contains <!-- embedded --> comment"))
```

This allows you to supply separate start and end tokens, or a single one if the start and end are the same.  It also creates a reusable function, so you could write:

```
const betweenRainbows = betweenTokens('rainbow')
betweenRainbows('rainbow pot of gold rainbow') //=> ' pot of gold '
```

Comment: I'm getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>

Comment: Sorry, reformatted badly after I ran it.  Fixed now.

Comment: And I think it's the best answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to achieve that with `split()`. It will work if there are only two same

```js
function getTextBetween(string,word){
    //if there word in not present in string 2 times
    if(string.indexOf(word) === string.lastIndexOf(word) || string.indexOf(word) === -1) return ''
 return string.split(word)[1].trim();
}
console.log(getTextBetween("rainbow Text rainbow text after","rainbow"));
console.log(getTextBetween("text before rainbow this is between rainbow this is not between","rainbow"));
console.log(getTextBetween("rainbo this is between rainbow this is not between","rainbow"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below using RegEx will achieve the result regardless of where the word *Text* exists in the string, making it much more extensible.

As you stated you are looking for the word *Text*..

```
var str = "rainbow Text rainbow"
var str2 = "rainbow rainbow Text rainbow rainbow"
var str3 = "rainbow rainbow rainbow Text rainbow"

getTextBetween(str,"Text")
getTextBetween(str2, "Text")
getTextBetween(str3, "Text")

function getTextBetween(str,word) {
    let pat = new RegExp(word)
    let result = pat.exec(str)
    console.log(result[0])
}
```